# Micro Services Architecture if using Sequelize as an ORM

Tags: node.js, socket.io, sequelize.js

I'm developing a chat application that consists of several micro-services or nodes. And to handle database I use Sequelize ORM.

However, I've two separate nodes one for handling socket messages and another one is a general API server. Both of them have to use Sequelize.

How can I use Sequelize in both? I don't want the same code to copy paste in two different services.

Answer (score 1):

What we have done in our project, is to connect socket server and API server. Thus API server is a special socket client for the socket server. Thus if we need to do some db query we pass data to-fro between them.